# Access Bugzilla in a Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: apache, azure, ubuntu, bugzilla

I launched an Ubuntu virtual machine on microsoft azure and connected via ssh into the instance.

I followed all the installation instructions at:

http://bugzilla.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/quick-start.html

After following the installation instructions, I am able to login into bugzilla via lynx.

The installation worked except I cannot log in to bugzilla on my PC via my browser, (chrome/ edge).

Typing in the IP address results in a timeout error (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT).  I would expect instead to see the bugzilla login page.

I went to `var/www/data` and set urlbase in params.json:

```
"urlbase" : "http://40.127.99.16",
```

But still I cannot login.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does "cannot log in" mean?  Are you getting an authentication error? Unable to connect?  Are there firewall rules in place that would block the connection?

Comment: @larsks Typing in the ip address results in the system timing out.  This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT  -- edited question to reflect and removed picture to stop downvotes.

Comment: @larsks you can try following the link if interested - http://40.127.99.16.  It is the actual machine I am working on.

Comment: @larsks you were correct.  I had to open port 80 in azure for TCP access.  Can you add as answer and I will accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Typing in the IP address result in a timeout error (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT). I would expect instead to see the bugzilla login page.

This typically means that something between your browser and the server is preventing the connection.  Typical culprits are either firewall rules on the remote server itself (managed with `iptables`), or in the remote cloud environment (managed using some some sort of platform-specific web interface or API).